# Kivy Configuration Ignored

Tags: python-2.7, kivy

I am working on Ubuntu 14.04 64bit. Default python 2.7.x package. Custom built Kivy (rather, it is not the kivy supplied in the repositories. I used pip to gather dependencies and build Kivy in a Virtualenv)

For some reason, I seem to have no control over a large portion of my runtime Configuration. I have tried using environment variables, *kivi.ini* in my working directory and home directory. I have tried directly importing the **kivy.Config** module at various different points in the runtime (before the Kivy App is built, during, after).

It seems that I cannot configure certain Kivi settings (default screen size for instance). My Kivy application is quite functional, but I am having trouble finding where Kivi looks for default configurations, and where the proper place is to override. I have tried many different ways, but it seems there is some master configuration that is taking priority and I am not able to override.

Am I missing something simple? Does this have anything to do with the virtualenv (and how Kivy was built)?

Answer (score 1):

> I have tried directly importing the kivy.Config module at various different points in the runtime (before the Kivy App is built, during, after).

If this is to work, it should be before anything else is imported.

Also, kivy is probably looking for the config file in `~/.kivy/config.ini`.

Comment: Indeed, you were right about `~/.kivy/config.ini`. I'm not sure if I was reading old docs, or if I was referencing something third party, but I was convinced I had told it not to use `HOME`, (this is a devel stage for Android deploy).

Comment: Still have trouble with kivy.Config. Some parts work, some don't. I'm having problems setting window size `Config.set"graphics", "width", 1024.0)`. It throws system errors. And this is right at the top.

Comment: Can you paste the output? Also, what happens it you set the size by setting kivy.core.window.Window.size instead?

Comment: I will get on that later this evening and edit my post with your requests.